# Spring: Overhead of @Transactional(readOnly = true) without existing transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

What is the overhead of annotating a method with @Transactional(readOnly = true) that is invoked without an existing current transaction? This is compared to not having the annotation there at all.

This is specifically with Hibernate as the JPA provider and MySQL as the database.

My current understanding is that adding the @Transactional annotation will have the following effect:

- Instruct Spring to create a proxy class and new transaction context
- Set the FlushMode.NEVER in the current Hibernate Session
- SetReadOnly(true) will be called on the JDBC connection

Is this correct?